# Pipe send command as input to another program - Telegram

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, pipe, telegram

I am running `telegram-cli` from a terminal.
I would like to execute commands like `contact_list` and manage their output through another script.
I run `telegram-cli` like this `./telegram-cli > pipe` and in another terminal I run this script `read_and_execute.sh`

```
   #!/bin/bash
pipe="/home/me/Download/tg/bin/pipe" 
while true
    do
        input=$(cat<"$pipe")
        if [[ $input =~ exit ]] 
        then
            exit 0
        else
            echo "output found"
        fi
    done
```

Using it, I should read the `telegram-cli` output, but how can I send commands to it? For example, I would like to get the messages of one contact, copy them in a file and then delete these messages from telegram.

Comment: Should I use also my approach to manage the output?

Comment: @pynexj I don't understand how should I use the .sock file

Comment: @pynexj what is that code supposed to do?

Comment: this is the output of that: bash-4.3$ exit
exit
it doesn't seem correct